# Collecting the values of all the checked boxes

Tags: jquery

In the sample code below. When I click the first check box I get an alert but for the second check box I don`t get an alert. I believe, this could be because the id's are same. Can someone show how to over come this. I want a way to have all the checked boxes values saved in the list and removed when unchecked.

```
$(function(){
    $('#abc').click(updateList);
});

function updateList() {
    var allVals = [];
    $('#abc').each(function() {
         allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(allVals);
}

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="abc" /> 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="abc" /> 2
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Not working JSFiddle sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/MvE4B/)

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, use class to group similar elements

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="abc" /> 1
```

then

```
$(function(){
    $('.abc').change(updateList);
});

function updateList() {
    var allVals = $('.abc').map(function() {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    alert(allVals);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cj25A/)

If you want to select only the checked checkboxes then

```
$(function(){
    $('.abc').change(updateList);
});

function updateList() {
    var allVals = $('.abc:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    alert(allVals);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5rZwZ/)

Comment: Simple things. Awesome !!